# How to use regex to extract string in SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

Documentation says:

`regexp_extract(string, pattern)` → `varchar`
Returns the first substring matched by the regular expression pattern in string
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html

I have the following query

```
select regexp_extract('sssshttps://jira.domain.com/browse/PR-6835hhhh',
'/(https.*\/browse\/)(\w+\-\d+)/g')
```

This return `null` when it should return `https://jira.domain.com/browse/PR-6835`
The regexp seems OK it works in many regexp tools that I checked.
Why I can't extract the substring of the url link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that forward slash and dash are not regex metacharacters, and so do not need to be escaped, at least not in Presto regex.  Consider this version:

```
select regexp_extract('sssshttps://jira.domain.com/browse/PR-6835hhhh',
                      'https.*?/browse/\w+-\d+')
```

This should return:

```
https://jira.domain.com/browse/PR-6835
```

Your current regex appears to be coming from some other language, such as JavaScript or PHP, where the regex literal has a delimiter `/`, therefore requiring that `/` needs to be escaped.

I just edited my answer to use lazy dot `.*?` when matching content between `https` and the first `/browse`.  This should fix the edge case mentioned in your comment where `.*` is matching across multiple URLs.

Comment: It works in some cases but not in others.. for example: `https://jira.domain.com/browse/PR-6838">https://jira.domain.com/browse/PR-6838` with this input it doesnt extract the string correctly..

Comment: @HaloKu Check the updated answer, you should be using lazy dot `.*?` here.

Comment: thank you. I think there is only one last edge case where this doesnt work : `https://d2x3x42.something.com/125f/f9e7e0f-c43e.png" /></div><div>bla bla ( refer to <a href="https://jira.domain.com/browse/PR-1000` Not sure I understand why the code doesn't extract it correctly. it just gives everything

Comment: OK, this is where regex needs to stop.  Regex is not suitable for matching nested HTML content like this.  I could give you another workaround, but I won't, because there are other edge cases too.

Comment: What I'm after is just extract a link from a huge field. The template is very simple extract occurrence of `https://*/browse/*-[NUMBERS]` it shouldn't be complicated

Comment: OK based on your answer I just changed it to : `https://jira.domain.com/browse/\w+-\d+` and eveything works now!

Comment: @HaloKu lolz, i was looking for my solution and your expression worked for me :D
i wanted to extract R10 till first space
regexp_extract('8932 - 840085 - sss cov R10963-10978-COV-2067 xxx333', 'R10963.*?\w+-\d+')